# Sourcetree, View file in old version/commit

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

How do I view a particular file from a particular commit/version?

I have seen the solution where you view the file in (any) History, right-click it and select *Log Selected* and then choose *Open Selected Version*. However, this only works when I can find the file in History, which means I need to find a commit/version where the file was updated. I don't have this info.

I have also seen solutions where I can checkout the old version. However, I'd like to avoid this. I have current files open in editors and want to keep them there, unchanged. Generally, I find that checking stuff out and creating new branches sometimes creates annoying head/branch/whatever errors that I'd just as well avoid just to view a single old file.

I used to use TortoiseHG where I could right-click any version, choose to view the files in that version, get a window showing all files, and then open any file from there as a temp file.